# How to avoid browser redirect caching

Tags: http, caching, browser, redirect

It's not the fist time that i stuck to this problem.
Everytime when i use an 301 redirect, the browser caches it. When i change the redirect in my app, i manualy have to clear my browsers cache.

This is not very welcome for an website as you will understand.
Is there an solution to avoid this caching?

Currently i got an list of new redirects from my customer. In my .htaccess, i replaced the old ones for the new ones, but it doesn't toke effect.

When i cleared my browser cache, it seems to work propper.

Any solutions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To quote the [HTTP specification on the 301 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2):

> **301 Moved Permanently**
>
> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any
>   future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned
>   URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically
>   re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new
>   references returned by the server, where possible. This response is
>   cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

Hence, the fact that browsers cache the redirected URI shouldn't be a surprise, since it's done as specified.

To get around this problem, most sites use 302 (307 could also be used).

Comment: Thanks! It was first ment as a permanent, not as a temporary redirect. As i read the 301 specifications i understand the meaning of it, and that the answer is clear: you just can't because 301 is not temporary but permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more relevant quote from HTTP/1.1 spec (in addition to @Bruno 's answer):

> **13.4 Response Cacheability**
>
> ...
>
> A response received with a status code of 200, 203, 206, 300, 301 or
> 410 MAY be stored by a cache and used in reply to a subsequent
> request, subject to the expiration mechanism, unless a cache-control
> directive prohibits caching.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.4