# Added a PHP redirection script to my Wordpress page. Works on some computers, but not on others. What's going on?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, http-redirect

I'm the webmaster of a Wordpress-based website, and recently, I added some code to the top of the index.php file in the Wordpress theme. This code, intended to be the first thing executed when the website loads, is meant to redirect to one of 1000 websites if the URL is www.website.com/index.php?website=random

The code, written in PHP, is as follows (put only 5 links for simplicity purposes):

```
<?php

    $random_vid = array('http://www.URL1.com',
                        'http://www.URL2.com',
                        'http://www.URL3.com',
                        'http://www.URL4.com',
                        'http://www.URL5.com'
                       );

    if ($_GET['website'] == "random") {
        $key = time() % count($random_vid);
        header('Location: ' . $random_vid[$key]); 
    }

?>
```

The problem is that this scripts works fine on some computers (redirects to a random site as intended), but doesn't work on others. In the cases in which it doesn't work, clicking on www.website.com/?website=random will redirect people to the same website infinitely (so, always redirected to URL1.com no matter how many times you click on the link).

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Wordpress, with individual browsers, or with my code. Honestly, I'm stumped and I don't know what to do. Can anyone shed some insight as to what is going on?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like header() actually working (e.g. there's no silent/hidden "headers already sent" error)?

Comment: I'd guess they're caching the redirect. Chrome's fairly aggressive about that.

Comment: @ceejayoz has the right idea; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Web browsers [cache redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136315/how-to-avoid-browser-redirect-caching). When you send the Location: header to the browser, it will remember for a period of time that it got this response the last time it requested `http://www.website.com/index.php?website=random`, so it will skip making the request and follow the redirect it got last time.

Ideally, there are `301 Moved Permanently` redirects and `302 Moved Temporarily` redirects, PHP sends a 302 when you set a `Location` header, unless told otherwise, and 302s [aren't meant to be cached](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3), but [Chrome does appear to cache 302 responses](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103458) under certain circumstances and certain versions.

Your best bet is to make sure you are sending a 302 redirect and instructing the browser explicitly not to cache the response:

```
<?php

    $random_vid = array('http://www.URL1.com',
                        'http://www.URL2.com',
                        'http://www.URL3.com',
                        'http://www.URL4.com',
                        'http://www.URL5.com'
                       );

    if ($_GET['website'] == "random") {
        $key = time() % count($random_vid);
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: Sat, 20 Apr 2000 05:00:00 GMT");
        header('Location: ' . $random_vid[$key], true, 302); 
    }

?>
```

After making these changes, you'll most likely still need to clear the caches of affected browsers you've been testing with to get them to honor the new headers.

Comment: Another option is replacing the links to `http://example.com/?website=random` with `http://example.com/?website=random&random=<random number>` so it's a different URL each time.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an argument to the Location; perhaps that will keep it from being cached:

```
header('Location: ' . $random_vid[$key] . '?t=' . time());
```

Comment: Good idea simple and obtrusive

Comment: This will typically prevent the *target page* from being cached, to some extent, but won't prevent the redirect itself from being cached in the first place! The problem is not getting the `Location: ` response to change every time -- it already does so. The problem is getting the browser to actually look at it every time.

Comment: Ah, good point. In that case you could give an argument to your redirect page, so that the browser thinks it's dynamic. In other words, instead of making index.php do the redirect, you could have index.php redirect to 'redirect.php?k=' . $random_vid[$key], which then redirects to $k. Or, even simpler, just put a Pragma: no-cache header (or the equivalent meta tag) on index.php and see if that prevents it from being cached.

Comment: In your first example you still have the same problem on certain browsers that don't do the right thing with pages with query parameters. If the key into $random_vid is part of the first redirect, the specific page to redirect to in redirect #2 is cached as part of redirect #1. This is the case in, for example, certain versions of Chrome.